# This python code isn't working for me and I do not know why. Tell me if there any promblem with the code

Tags: python

I don't know why this python code isn't working, please tell me why.

```py
weight = int(input("Enter your weight:"))
Weightscale = (input("(L)bs or (K)g:"))

if Weightscale.lower == "L":
                  ans = (weight * 0.45)
                  print(f"You are {ans} Kg")

else:
    ans = (weight / 0.45)
    print(f"You are {ans} pound")
```

Comment: Where is the *weight* variable declared? Weightscale.lower is a function (not the result of calling it). You may have meant Weightscale.lower() but then to compare with an uppercase string wouldn't make sense

Comment: Make sure the weight variable is defined before this block of code and replace "Weightscale.lower" with "Weightscale.lower()"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why isn't it working? Other than the issues found in the answers below, what is *your* definition of not working? Please include your research and errors in your question to help us answer

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `weight` as a `float` to have decimal values.

You must use `()` to call `lower`. Then your `lower` condition must compare to a lowercase letter `"l"`, not `"L"`:

```py
weightscale = input("(L)bs or (K)g: ")
weight = float(input(f"Enter weight in {weightscale}: "))

# Lower needs (), then make the "L" lower too -> "l"
if weightscale.lower() == "l":
    ans = (weight * 0.45)
    print(f"You are {ans} Kg")

else:
    ans = (weight / 0.45)
    print(f"You are {ans} pound")
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice three mistakes in your code:

- `weight` is not declared
- `Weightscale.lower` should be a function call, i.e. `Weightscale.lower()`
- `Weightscale.lower()` will never be equal to `"L"`, so your `if` block will never be treated. You should do one of the following:

  - `Weightscale.lower() == "l"`
  - `Weightscale.upper() == "L"`

Answer (score 0):

Using lower and comparing "L", try:

```
if Weightscale.lower() == "l":
```